# how to run one program created exe file from another program in turbo c?

Tags: c++, linker, turbo-c++

i am developed a program in dev c++ compiler name of file is `CorrectPrgm.cpp` and want to run `CorrectPrgm.exe` created by `CorrectPrgm.cpp` file. from `Le.cpp` which was developed in turbo c++ 3.0 compiler and my need is at the time of running `Le.cpp` i want to invoke/run `CorrectPrgm.exe`.  The CorrectPrgm file accepts file name from user and produces output as list of tokens.

i have tried like this:

```
system("C:\\CorrectPrgm.EXE");
```

not working..
any other way to call...
Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: [Use a modern compiler/IDE, not TurboC++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961828/why-not-turbo-c/1962710)

Comment: i have tried in MS Visual c++ 2010 using system("CorrectPrgm");it worked fine..But how to do same in turbo c compiler. i have exist graphics program there i want to link this program that's problem. or any other way to use that graphics program in MS Visual c++ 2010 compiler..

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows Vista and above, probably you can't run it, as I believe this would be a 16-bit DOS applications. If it's 32-bit DOS app (proteced mode through DPMI, but unlikely) then it might run too, but that was too long ago to remmember how.

On Windows 7, you can install Windows XP mode (actually Virtual PC builtin kind of), and run it from there. XP still supports 16-bit apps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use one of the `exec` or `spawn` functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a separate process for the program you want to invoke. But you will face a lot of problems. Firstly. `correctPrgm.exe` and `le.exe` will execute in two separate process. So you have to consider interprocess communication.
The best thing I'd suggest is break the CorrectPrgm.exe source file in functions and call the functions you need.  Even you can use library and header file(s) to get the functionality of those functions.
You can also create threads. But then you have to design the threads (in one thread the `CorrectPrgm` will run) very carefully.